# Does an audio stream from an internet radio station contain song information

Tags: audio-streaming, id3, internet-radio

Not sure if this is the right place to ask.

I am wondering if audio streams from internet  radio stations can (and do) contain song information such as title and artist? I suppose there are many formats that may or may not support this, so *'Yes but only if x and y'* would be a valid answer.

Related: If this is possible, and the info is there, is for instance VLC able to show it?

Comment: Does [get info from streaming radio - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44050266/get-info-from-streaming-radio) answer your question?

Comment: @DavidPostill yeah, I guess it does, icw harrymc's answer it would be Yes and No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the information is there.

As regarding VLC, see the bug-report
[No Metadata (song title / artist / ..) on playback of online radio stream](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/26594).

The answer by the developer from 2022 was :

> ICY metadata is an ancient hack basically as there is no other way to do streaming metadata for MP3 streams and it is what the stream uses, but we do not yet support it over https. I did not have time yet to fix it.

This metadata support may or may not arrive in VLC sometime
in the future.

Comment: I should have tried other players before asking ;-) Vlc on Android does show artist and title! So yes, the info is indeed there

Comment: So the developer has already added this feature. Good news.

Comment: Yes, just not to the windows version afaics

Answer (score 2):

[https://www.amazon.com/RTL-SDR-Blog-RTL2832U-Software-Defined/dp/B0BMKZCKTF?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BMKZCKTF)

Here is 1 potential hardware option.  Depending on what you buy an antenna may or may not be included and may have to be purchased separately.

You want a generic one like the rtlsdr as it uses a generic driver that nrsc5 is compatible.

[image: rtlsdr]

The answer is YES, and it can contain a bunch of other information.

My local broadcast radio stations are in HD radio(digital) and all contain a bunch of metadata.

You may need a SDR (software defined radio) on a PC to receive and decode it.

Also you area need to have the digital radio signal instead of the old school analog.  However, at least in the US that is usually the case.

When I do this on linux, I get:

1. song name
2. album art usually lowish quality <10kb or less normally.
3. low quality weather maps (think 16 or 256 color)
   [image]
4. Text info including the GPS location of the radio towers.

> DopplerWeatherRadarProtocolVersionID="1.0"
> DWR_Area_ID= StationList=
> Coordinates="(###,###)";"(###,###)"
> Legend_Rain="(1,(0,255,0))";"(2,(0,170,0))";"(3,(0,102,0))";"(4,(255,238,0))";"(5,(238,119,0))";"(6,(221,0,0))"
> Legend_MixIce="(1,(255,170,255))";"(2,(244,85,176))"
> Legend_Snow="(1,(0,255,255))";"(2,(0,0,255))"
> CopyrightNotice="Copyright © 2023 iHeartMedia, Inc. All rights
> reserved."

Note: I deleted the GPS location and station list, for privacy.

> TrafficMapProtocolVersionID="1.3" TrafficMapID="0" StationList=" "
> NumRows="3" NumColumns="3" NumTransmittedTiles="9" >CoordinatesRow1=""
> CoordinatesRow2=""
> CoordinatesRow3=""
> BackgroundRGBColor="(194,187,96)" CopyrightNotice="Copyright © 2014
> iHeartMedia, Inc. All rights reserved."

*2 I have seen a few up to 15kb, but this is rare.

https://github.com/theori-io/nrsc5

This software will decode and saving into file all the available metadata.

I have tested the software in linux, and know first hand what it outputs.

Comment: What's this, some kind of dab receiver? I was thinking more of internet-radio streaming

Comment: Yes it is a kind of dab, it's called SDR or software define radio that can listen on a wide variety of frequencies.  You said radio station not streaming radio, so that is how I answered the question.  Your standard digital FM signal has this metadata now-a-days.

Comment: I added the internet-radio tag. But that's ok, I just learned something new.